# React Redux - state returned in mapStateToProps has reducer names as properties?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have 2 reducers that are combined in a Root Reducer, and used in a store. 
First reducer 'AllTracksReducer" is supposed to return an object and the second 'FavoritesReducer' an array.

When I create a container component and a mapStateToProps method in connect, for some reason the returned state of the store is an object with 2 reducer objects which hold data, and not just an object containing correposding data, as expected.

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
       debugger:
       console.dir(state)
       //state shows as an object with 2 properties, AllTracksReducer and       FavoritesReducer. 


        return {
            data: state.AllTracksReducer.data,
            isLoading: state.AllTracksReducer.isLoading
        }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllTracksContainer);
```

so, in mapStateToProps, to get to the right state property, i have to say
state.AllTracksReducer.data...  But I was expecting the data to be available directly on the state object?

Comment: That's what the function `combineReducers` does. it maps your reducer functions to their own keys on state. otherwise you would certainly have collisions as you add reducers in your app. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 13):

Yep, this is a common semi-mistake.  It's because you're using likely using ES6 object literal shorthand syntax to create the object you pass to `combineReducers`, so the names of the imported variables are also being used to define the state slice names.

This issue is explained in the Redux docs, at [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers/).

Comment: What mistake ? Isn't this common behavior? How'll you correct that in case it is?  Say to use state.variableName directly instead of state.reducerName

Comment: The mistake is trying to use ES6 object literal shorthand, and directly passing in an imported reducer name, like `combineReducers({userReducer})`.  This will result in `state.userReducer`. Per the linked article, having "reducer" in a state slice name is considered poor practice. A better approach would be `combineReducers({users : userReducer})`.

Comment: Oh! I got confused if ES6 shorthand or not, having reducer name returned is a semi-mistake.  Cool!

Comment: @markerikson The link is dead. Will you update it with this one? https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers/

Answer (score 5):

Create some selectors that receive the whole state (or the reducer-specific state) and use it in your `mapStateToProps` function. Indeed the name you define when you `combineReducers` will be the topmost state keys, so your selectors should take that into account:

```
const getTracks = (state) => state.allTracks.data
const isLoading = state => state.allTracks.isLoading
```

This assumes you combine your reducers with `allTracks` as they key like here:

```
combineReducers({
  allTracks: allTracksReducer
})
```

And then you can use those selectors in your mapper, like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoading: isLoading(state),
  tracks: getTracks(state)
})
```

There's a delicate link between your `combineReducers` call and your selectors. If you change the state key name you'll have to update your selectors accordingly.

It helps me to think of action creators as "setters" and selectors as "getters", with the reducer function being simply the persistence part. You call your setters (dispatching action creators) when you want to modify your state, and use your selectors as shown to get the current state and pass it as props to your components.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I went down a terrible rabbit hole with this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's how it supposed to work. When you're using combineReducers, you're literally mapping the name of a reducer to the reducer function.

If it bothers you, I would suggest a little syntactical magic if you're using es2016 (though it seems you're not) like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { data, isLoading } = state.allTracksReducer;
    return {
        data: data,
        isLoading: isLoading
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllTracksContainer);
```

Remember, state is the one source of truth that possesses all your reducers.

Comment: I found this approach simple. And, my problem was compounded by the fact I was trying to access my reducer with redueer and was getting undefined all the time. Damn me!